# Bash: Find and delete duplicate files from different folders base on name and size of each file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have merged several old folders of mp3 together via MusicBrainz Picard https://picard.musicbrainz.org/
It did an amazing job identifying mp3 and properly organise them in a structured folder which I want.

But now I am finding several duplicates in the following format:

```
size    file_path_and_name  
3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name>.mp3  
3164554 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (1).mp3  
3337687 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (2).mp3  
3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (3).mp3
```

I tried to use `fdupes`, but it is not working for me because the mp3 are not exactly the same files.
Often, each "duplicate" is a slightly different version, sometimes the quality is different, sometimes the file is corrupted sometimes the song is for a different album.

I don't need to have multiple copies of the same file for each album.

What I was planning in doing is to identify the biggest file  in size (*biggest always better! ;)* ) among the duplicates and delete the rest.

I am still learning bash so I decided to go a step at the time, but I got blocked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what i have so far:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tempfile="duplicates.tmp"
tempfilesorted="duplicatessorted.tmp"

# with the following I am identifying every duplicate and create a document with the list
find . -regex '.* ([0-99]).*' > $tempfile
# in $tempfile we would find something like
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name> (1).mp3
# ./<artist_2>/<artist_2> - <song_name> (1).mp3
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name> (2).mp3

# I am removing the (xx) numbering
sed -i -e 's/ ([0-99])//g' $tempfile
# in $tempfile we would find something like
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name>.mp3
# ./<artist_2>/<artist_2> - <song_name>.mp3
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name>.mp3

# sorting and leave the unique entrances
sort $tempfile | uniq -u > $tempfilesorted
# example of result in $tempfilesorted
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name>.mp3
# ./<artist_2>/<artist_2> - <song_name>.mp3

# adding * at the end of the file name before the extension
sed -i -r 's/.mp3/*.mp3/' $tempfilesorted
# example of result in $tempfilesorted
# ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name>*.mp3
# ./<artist_2>/<artist_2> - <song_name>*.mp3

# my plan from here was simple:
# identify the bigger size and delete the remaining ones
while IFS= read -r line; do
#    ls -S "$line"
    echo "processing: $line"
done <  $tempfilesorted
```

Any suggestion?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Aaron I have updated the previous script with the following solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tempfile="duplicates.tmp"
tempfilesorted="duplicatessorted.tmp"

# with the following I am identifying every duplicate and create a document with the list
find . -regex '.* ([0-99]).*' > $tempfile

# I am removing the (x) numbering
sed -i -e 's/ ([0-9])//g' $tempfile

# sorting and leave the unique entrances
sort $tempfile > $tempfilesorted
# TO DO, I have no idea but the original solution using uniq:
# sort $tempfile | uniq -u > $tempfilesorted
# was skipping few lines, I will find a solution and update

# adding * at the end of the file name before the extension
sed -i -r 's/.mp3/*.mp3/' $tempfilesorted
# TO DO: modify so it works for any type of file, not just mp3

# Identify and rename temporary the bigger file
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "processing: $line"
    {
       # read the biggest file from the first line
       IFS=$'\007' read -r biggest_file its_size
       #mv -f "$biggest_file" "${biggest_file/ ([0-9]*).mp3/$'\177'.mp3}"
       mv -f "$biggest_file" "${biggest_file/ ([0-9]*)./OWpfUWNOdC.}"

       # read other files
       while IFS=$'\007' read -r other_file its_size; do
            rm "${other_file}"
       done
    } < <(find . -wholename "$line" -printf '%p\007%s\n' | sort -grt $'\007' -k 2)
done <  $tempfilesorted

# removing the added random string that was used to identify the bigger file
#find -type f -wholename "*OWpfUWNOdC*" -execdir  rename  's/$'\177'.mp3/.mp3/' '{}' \;
find . -type f -wholename "*OWpfUWNOdC*" -execdir  rename  's/OWpfUWNOdC././' '{}' \;
```

*information of why some amendments from the original proposed code by @Aaron :*

1. In the following scenario

```
 size    file_path_and_name  
3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name>.mp3  
3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (1).mp3
```

the original solution was deleting both files.
To solve this instead of moving the file to itself I have temporary renamed the file with a random string and in a second run finding the string and removing it.

2. I have modified the `find . -name` to `find . -wholename` because there were spaces in the file names

---

**strange stuff still happening:**

If I try to sort and uniq the following file, I will lose few entrances.
https://pastebin.com/8yvied22
Any ideas?

---

**help with the following**

As you can see in the code, I have tried to use the following symbol `$'\177'` instead of a random string.
I am able to find the files, but I cannot rename them.
You can find my proposed solution commented in the updated code.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `[0-99]` doesn't match what you think it does. regex doesn't have a concept of number, and therefore doesn't handle number ranges, just character ranges. That matches a single character between 0 and 9 (the second 9 being redundant) and missing duplicates with two digits. You can use `[0-9][0-9]?` or `[0-9]{1,2}` instead which matches one or two consecutive digits

Comment: Thank you @Aaron , as commented I am still learning, that is really useful to know.
Regards

Comment: `find . -wholename because there were spaces in the file` - It makes no sense, `-name` does not care about spaces.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk , possibly because it was a folder and file name?  
I am not sure, but it wasn't processing few file names and by using wholename it fixed it.  
I didn't really check or taste farther. 
I can give it a try later.

Comment: `-wholename` is the same as `-path`. Ie. it matches folder+filename not only filename. Like `find /usr/lib -name 'libc.so.*'` vs `find . -path '/usr/lib/libc.so.*'`

Answer (score 0):

You have reached a point where you are iterating over a list of globs which match duplicate files.

What remains is to retrieve the size of files matching those globs, to rename the largest one and to delete the others.

`find` can retrieve the sizes of files, using the relevant format specifiers of its `-printf` action :

```
find . -name "$line" -printf '%p\007%s\n'
```

In this `printf` format `%p` refers to the file's path, `%s` to its size, `\n` is a linefeed and `\007` is the ASCII BEL/Bell character. I'm using this because I plan to consider the lines as composed of two fields, and I must chose a character that I know will not be present in your file names (or their sizes, but that's easy) to use as delimiter of those fields.
The standard would be to use the NUL/Null byte, ASCII 0, but in this case I wasn't able to use it easily, so any other character I'm confident won't be found in your file names does the trick. James Bond did certainly not influence my choice at any point.

At this point I've got a list of files matching a glob mapped to their size, e.g.

> ```
> ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name> (1).mp312345
> ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name> (2).mp312223  
> ./<artist_1>/<artist_1> - <song_name>.mp312345
> ```

(I've used the unrelated UTF-8 pictograph "Bell" for improved readability where `\007` should be)

I need to distinguish the line with the largest size from the others. One solution is to sort those lines numerically over their second field, separated by `\007` :

```
sort -grt $'\007' -k 2
```

`-g` sorts numerically, `-t $'\007'` lets us define that our field separator is `\007`, `-k 2` defines the second field as the sort key and `-r` reverse the sort order, letting us retrieve the biggest file from the first line which is easier.

Now we just have to retrieve the file name from the first line, rename it, then iterate over the remaining lines, retrieve the file name and delete it :

```
{
   # read the biggest file from the first line
   IFS=$'\007' read -r biggest_file its_size
   mv "$biggest_file" $(sed 's/ ([0-9]*).mp3/.mp3/' <<<"$biggest_file")
  
   # read other files
   while IFS=$'\007' read -r other_file its_size; do
     rm "$other_file"
   done
}
```

Now to fit the pieces together :

```
[...]
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "processing: $line"
    
    {
       # read the biggest file from the first line
       IFS=$'\007' read -r biggest_file its_size
       mv "$biggest_file" $(sed 's/ ([0-9]*).mp3/.mp3/' <<<"$biggest_file")
      
       # read other files
       while IFS=$'\007' read -r other_file its_size; do
         rm "$other_file"
       done
    } < <(find . -name "$line" -printf '%p\007%s\n' | sort -grt $'\007' -k 2)
done <  $tempfilesorted
```

Note that I didn't focus on performances in this answer as I wanted to build upon what you had already done and provide a pure bash answer and I expect they won't be great. If it is too slow to your taste, you should leave only the first file selection up to `bash` and have an higher-level language such as `awk`, `python`, `perl`, etc. handle the file list.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron , I will give it a try in few hours, but your answer makes a lot of sense already.  
I have been playing with bash for a bit and I really like it, mainly I have been modifying already present linux scripts, this is the first time I needed to do something with files and I was getting confused.

In regards of higher language, I already started with the basics of Python, I will try to create the same solution in Python next and see how it goes.
I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> size    file_path_and_name  
> 3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name>.mp3  
> 3164554 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (1).mp3  
> 3337687 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (2).mp3  
> 3130248 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (3).mp3
> ```
>
> identify the biggest file in size (biggest always better! ;) ) among the duplicates and delete the rest.

I will call `<artist name> - <song name>.mp3` as a "normalized filename" in comments below. Note that the script will not work with filenames with newlines and `\007` bytes.

```
# print path, filename and size on separate lines
find . -type f -printf '%p\n%f\n%s\n' |
# extract the `<song name> (this number).mp3`
# print 'path, normalized filename, size' separated by 0x07 byte
sed 'N ; s/ ([0-9]*)\(\.[^\.]*\)$/\1/ ; N ; s/\n/\x07/g' |
# sort by normalized filename, then by size !!
sort -t$'\007' -r -k2 -k3n |
tee >(
    # extract the biggest!
    # he will be the first unique normalized filename in second column
    awk -F$'\007' 'prev != $2 {print $1} {prev=$2}' \
        > biggest_files_in_size.txt
) |
# Filter first normalized filenames - ie. "extract the rest"
# So print only if normalized filename is a duplicate since the last line
# outputs paths only
awk -F$'\007' 'prev == $2 {print $1} {prev=$2}' |
# remove those files
# replace `printf "remove: %s\n"` with `rm -v` to really remove those files
xargs -d$'\n' printf "remove: %s\n"
```

To really remove the files, replace `printf "remove: %s\n"` on the last line with `rm`. With the following recreation of file structure:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r size file; do
    mkdir -p ./"$(dirname "$file")"
    : > "$file"
    dd if=/dev/zero of="$file" bs=1 count="$size" status=none
# two columns - size and filename
done <<'EOF'
3 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name>.mp3
4 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (1).mp3  
6 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (2).mp3  
5 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (3).mp3  
1 <artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (123).mp3  
1 Kamil/Kamil - this should stay (3).mp3
2 Kamil/Kamil - remove the 10 (8).mp3
1 Kamil/Kamil - remove the 10 (10).mp3
EOF
```

It will print out:

```
remove: ./Kamil/Kamil - remove the 10 (10).mp3
remove: ./<artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (3).mp3
remove: ./<artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (1).mp3
remove: ./<artist name>/<artist name> - <song name>.mp3
remove: ./<artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (123).mp3
```

And the content of `biggest_files_in_size.txt` will be:

```
./Kamil/Kamil - this should stay (3).mp3
./Kamil/Kamil - remove the 10 (8).mp3
./<artist name>/<artist name> - <song name> (2).mp3
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/OnlyFlickeringStruct).

PS. Somehow in repl `sort -t$'\007' -k2 -k3rn` produces incorrect sorting order on the 3rd column, it's not reversed. I don't know why, it's strange, I think it should work. So I used `sort -t$'\007' -r -k2 -k3n` above.